# Optimal number of folds for k-fold cross-validation

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, cross-validation, hyperparameters

Can anyone recommend some more formal method of establishing the optimal number of folds, less than the maximum possible one and not requiring time-consuming simulations (that would predictably find the top of the range of tested `k` values to be the best)?

**More info**

From theory and simulations we know that model metrics tend to generally increase (with some variance) as a function of the number of folds (`k`). It is therefore suboptimal to use anything less than the maximum number of folds still feasible given data size and time constraints.

So using standard default values of 5 or 10 folds is in fact an example of hyperparameter optimization too, but one collectively performed, so they need not be pre-optimized, but switched according to time constraints for model training. As a special case, in time-consuming training setups such as deep learning there is no time for multiple folds, so only single validation set is normally used.

Answer (score 0):

One imperfect solution can be borrowed from PCA [scree plots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scree_plot) - it's the so called **elbow point**, but it needs formalization, and it requires those simulations over folds numbers that we wanted to avoid.

For example, according to my simulation over hundreds of models (sklearn breast cancer data classification) the optimum elbow point would be around 3-5 folds:

[image: Out-of-fold AUC vs folds_number (plot)]